# W3C Selectors API implement jquery Selector $('a span:contains("myText")')

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-selectors, css-selectors, selectors-api

I want to change

```
$('a span:contains("myText")').click();
```

to

```
var ev = document.createEvent("MouseEvents");
ev.initEvent("click", true, true);
document.querySelector(???).dispatchEvent(ev);
```

what is ??? should i type?

Comment: yes you should type... search document.querySelector() to find out how it works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

unfortunately, what you are asking cannot be done with a single line, as JavaScript does not have a 'contains' selector.

what you must do, is get all the `'a span'` elements using `document.querySelectorAll()` and then iterate through them and check if they contain `'myText'` in them.

here is an example [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/TheBanana/Hn8T8/)

html:

```
<a href="/three"><span>banana button</span></a>
<a><span>orange button</span></a>
```

css:

```
span {
    width:100px;
    height:25px;
    border:2px solid red;
    cursor:pointer;
}
```

js:

```
var ev = document.createEvent("MouseEvents");
ev.initEvent("click", true, true);
var all_spans = document.querySelectorAll("a span");
for (i = 0; i < all_spans.length; i++) {
    if (all_spans[i].innerText.indexOf("banana")>-1) {
        all_spans[i].dispatchEvent(ev);
    }
}
```